# java.awt.List how to change existing element name in list?

Tags: java, list, user-interface, awt

How i can change existing element name in java.awt.List ? I know element id. Elements was added by list.add(name, id), but how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [replaceItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html#replaceItem%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to change the item.

Comment: When i use replaceItem in program i see, what that element is deleted and created again, i just want to update String name of element.